# ObjectDisposedException in HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, compact-framework, webrequest

I create a web request in Compact framework as

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("Url");

using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
     streamWriter.Write("body");

using (HttpWebResponse response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
     string json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

and i get an `ObjectDisposedException`. 
I blame `response.GetResponseStream()` for this error, but what is wrong with this code?

The stack trace is

```
System.ObjectDisposedException 
ObjectDisposedException-   at System.Threading.Timer.throwIfDisposed()
   at System.Threading.Timer.Change(UInt32 dueTime, UInt32 period)
   at System.Threading.Timer.Change(Int32 dueTime, Int32 period)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.ConnectionClient.Read(Byte[] data, Int32 offset, Int32 length)
   at System.Net.HttpReadStream.NetworkRead(Byte[] data, Int32 offset, Int32 length)
   at System.Net.ContentLengthReadStream.doRead(Byte[] data, Int32 offset, Int32 length)
   at System.Net.HttpReadStream.ReadToDrain(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 length)
   at System.Net.HttpReadStream.doClose()
   at System.Net.ContentLengthReadStream.doClose()
   at System.Net.HttpReadStream.Finalize()
```

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that it's due to you disposing the `StreamWriter` which, in turn, disposes the request stream.  What that does to the request itself, I don't know, but I'd make a guess that's where things are falling down.

You could always dig into the BCL with Reflector to see exactly what happens, but it might just be faster and easier to try a test like this:

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("Url");
StreamWriter streamWriter;
try
{
    streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    streamWriter.Write("body");

    using (HttpWebResponse response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
finally
{
    streamWriter.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Hello, the "write method" uses the GetRequestStream while the "read" uses the GetResponseStream. These are handled internally as common in HttpWebRequest?

Comment: I'm not certain how they're handled internally.  As I suggested, you could use Reflector to check the BCL source but it's probably faster to just try the code above.